# Proof that expression is integer

Tags: number-theory, induction

hi guys can you help me with this?

## Proof that expression is integer

## $$\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$$

Comment: This is also known as $(2n-1)!!$. See [Double Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). In particular, its [relation to the factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Relation_to_the_factorial) (for odd numbers).

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!} = \frac{(2n) \times (2n - 1) \times \cdots \times 1}{(2n) \times (2n - 2) \times \cdots \times 2} = (2n - 1) \times (2n - 3) \times \cdots \times 1 \in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$ then $(2n)!/2^{n}n! = 1$. Let $n \geq 1$. If $(2n)!/2^{n}n! = k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then 
$$
\frac{(2n+2)!}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!} = \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}{(2n+2)2^{n}n!} = (2n+1)k \in \mathbb{N},
$$
qed.